# Create list of tkinter canvas lines/points

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Many lines and points possible that I would like to be able to track when I line/point has been moused over. Is there any short codeable way of doing it or do I half to come up with hundreds/thousands of different element names.

I've tried

```
self.z[0].canvas.create_line()
self.z[1].canvas.create_line()
```

as well as

```
self.z(0).canvas.create_line()
self.z(1).canvas.create_line()
```

to only get back an error saying something like z can't be an integer, aka you can't do that stupid:)

Is there anyway to set up a nice for loop and create the lines/points and then be able to test test them once they are created.  I can test the points the way I want to be able to test them but I would just like an easier way of  creating the lines/points.

Worst case scenario is there a way of setting up something like

```
self.z1.canvas
self.z2.canvas
self.z3.canvas
```

but have 1,2,3 each be able to be increased through a for loop?  I'm not sure if I have ever seen something like what I'm suggesting be made mention of or not.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me ... so you want to create multiple lines on one canvas ? or are there multiple canvases ? why are you trying to get the `canvas` attribute from the element of the list `z` ?

Comment: One canvas with many lines/points on it and I want to be able to bring up an info sheet on the line/point whenever I scroll the mouse across the line/point.  I can detect the line scroll over and use it but I'm trying to figure out an easy way given the circumstances of naming the lines/points.  I would like to be able to use something as easy as line1, line2, line3, or like I've tried previously line[1],line[2],line[3] to making setting up the lines easy with a for loop.  All the line data is in a csv file which makes it easy but creating the named line seems to be more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you create an item on a canvas, it returns a unique id. You can store that id in a list.

```
self.lines = []
for x in range(1000):
    item = self.canvas.create_line(...)
    self.lines.append(item)
```

That being said, you don't need to keep any of these in an array to " track when I line/point has been moused over.". You can set up bindings for that.

Comment: Okay.  I hadn't even thought of the idea of trying to append the unique id.  Still too much to learn/understand yet:)  At least it looks like I might be able to really shortcut this now.